# LINQ 2 SQL doensn't insert entity with relationship

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

First a summary what we had before and what we did change: in our project we had multiple projects that had multiple DataContextes. Last week we merged all those DataContextes into one DataContext: this is because we now have all the relations and not everywhere at a random DataContext.

This progress went well, until we hit a wall: we have a table `Entities` and a table `Articles`. First we had the following code:

```
var article = new Article();
article.Entity = new Entity();
context.InsertOnSubmit(article);
```

We received a conflict on the relation `Article <> Entity`, so we tried the following:

```
var entity = new Entity();
context.InsertOnSubmit(entity);

var article = new Article();
context.InsertOnSubmit(article);
```

which also gave the same error. We enabled `context.Log` to check the queries that were executed. Whenever we tried to INSERT the entity a SELECT query was executed. So we tried to set the ConflictMode to FailOnFirstConflict, which did not throw anything and the SELECT was still executed.

We made our own INSERT that would attach the entity after:

```
var entity = new Entity();
CustomInsert(entity);
context.Attach(entity, false);

var article = new Article();
context.InsertOnSubmit(article);
```

which didn't work because it was complaining about a trigger. We disabled the trigger: and it worked! So in our minds we thought maybe the trigger also broke the L2S insert; so we reverted everything and tried to INSERT the entity with LINQ 2 SQL without the trigger: still a SELECT and not a INSERT, so it failed.

What we also tried:

- Removing the `LoadWith` in the options.
- Creating a new instance of the DataContext.

Now is the question: what could be the issue here? Did anyone else had this error and did you maybe fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The issue was the `Insert` in the DataContext. When you override this method LINQ 2 SQL expects that you insert the entity manually and doesn't insert the entity by itself.